# shapeless.~?>.witness[Nothing, Nothing, T](shapeless.~?>.rel[Nothing, Nothing])when upgrading scala version from 2 to 3

Tags: scala, shapeless, scala-3, scodec

I'm upgrading my scala project from version 2 to 3.

This is my build.sbt for  version scala version 2

```
    scalaVersion := "2.13.5"
    version := "1.0.0"
    libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.7"
    libraryDependencies += "org.scodec" %% "scodec-core" % "1.11.4"
    libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12" % "1.7.31"
```

Below is sample scala code -

```
    import scodec._
    import scodec.codecs._
    import scodec.bits._
    import scodec.codecs.implicits._
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory


    object AkkaEventSerializer {

      def toBinary(o: AnyRef): Array[Byte] =  o match {
        case e: Event => Codec.encode(e).require.toByteArray
        case x => throw new Exception(s"unexpected  object $x received which is ${x.getClass} type")
      }

      def fromBinary(bytes: Array[Byte], manifest: String): AnyRef = manifest match {
        case EventManifest => Codec[Event].decode(BitVector.apply(bytes)).require.value
        case x => throw new Exception(s"unexpected manifest $x in AdServerAkkaEventSerializer.fromBinary ")
      }

      final val EventManifest = classOf[Event].getName

      val  logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AkkaEventSerializer.getClass)

      case class Event(etype: Int, cp: Option[Double], userId: Option[String], buyerId: Option[String] = None)

    }
```

This is working fine for scala version 2.

Now I'm upgrading the scala version to 3.

Below is the build.sbt  -

```
    scalaVersion := "3.0.0"
    version := "1.0.0"
    crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.13.5", "3.0.0")
    libraryDependencies += ("com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.7").cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13)
    libraryDependencies += ("org.scodec" %% "scodec-core" % "1.11.4").cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13)
    libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12" % "1.7.31"
```

Below is the code scala version 3 -

```
    import scodec._
    import scodec.codecs._
    import scodec.bits._
    import scodec.codecs.implicits._
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    import shapeless.~?>.idKeyWitness
    import shapeless.~?>.idValueWitness
    import shapeless.~?>.witness


    object AkkaEventSerializer {

      def toBinary(o: AnyRef): Array[Byte] =  o match {
        case e: Event => Codec.encode(e).require.toByteArray
        case x => throw new Exception(s"unexpected  object $x received which is ${x.getClass} type")
      }

      def fromBinary(bytes: Array[Byte], manifest: String): AnyRef = manifest match {
        case EventManifest => Codec[Event].decode(BitVector.apply(bytes)).require.value
        case x => throw new Exception(s"unexpected manifest $x in AdServerAkkaEventSerializer.fromBinary ")
      }

      final val EventManifest = classOf[Event].getName

      val  logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AkkaEventSerializer.getClass)

      case class Event(etype: Int, cp: Option[Double], userId: Option[String], buyerId: Option[String] = None)

    }
```

When I compile this program, I get below error -

> [error] -- Error: /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/OS/scala3-maven-build-demo/src/main/scala/com/serialize/AkkaEventSerializer.scala:17:36
> [error] 17 |    case e: Event => Codec.encode(e).require.toByteArray
> [error]    |                                    ^
> [error]    |could not find Lazy implicit value of type scodec.Codec[com.serialize.AkkaEventSerializer.Event].
> [error]    |I found:
> [error]    |
> [error]    |    shapeless.~?>.witness[Nothing, Nothing, T](shapeless.~?>.rel[Nothing, Nothing])
> [error]    |
>
> [error]    |But method witness in trait NatTRel0 does not match type shapeless.Lazy[scodec.Codec[com.serialize.AkkaEventSerializer.Event]].
> [error] -- Error: /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/OS/scala3-maven-build-demo/src/main/scala/com/serialize/AkkaEventSerializer.scala:22:38
> [error] 22 |    case EventManifest => Codec[Event].decode(BitVector.apply(bytes)).require.value
> [error]    |                                      ^
> [error]    |could not find Lazy implicit value of type scodec.Codec[com.serialize.AkkaEventSerializer.Event].
> [error]    |I found:
>
> [error]    |
>
> [error]    |    shapeless.~?>.witness[Nothing, Nothing, T](shapeless.~?>.rel[Nothing, Nothing])
> [error]    |
>
> [error]    |But method witness in trait NatTRel0 does not match type
> shapeless.Lazy[scodec.Codec[com.serialize.AkkaEventSerializer.Event]].
> [error] two errors found
> [error] two errors found
> [error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed

I know we can compile scala 2.13 code using scala 3 version. But I couldn't for this code.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: "I know we can compile scala 2.13 code using scala 3 version." This is not true for macro libraries. http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/macros.html

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/compatibility-metaprogramming.html

Comment: So I've to update the shapeless to scala3 compatible version?

Comment: Yes, but there is no such version. For Shapeless 2 see https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/issues/1043 . And in https://github.com/typelevel/shapeless-3 there is no `~?>`, `Witness` etc.